# RxJava2 Flowable's concatMap and concatMapEager with observeOn has different behavior

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, concatmap

Should `publisher.observerOn(scheduler).concatMap(mapper, 1)` and `publisher.observerOn(scheduler).concatMapEager(mapper, 1, 1)` have same behavior when concatMapEager using concurrency with 1? 
I test `concatMap` and it may use different thread instead of scheduler from `observeOn` to call the mapper.

for example

```
Flowable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .concatMapEager(i -> {
            System.out.println("1>>>>trigger in thread:" + Thread.currentThread());
            return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
                executorService.submit(() -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                    }
                    emitter.onNext("" + i);
                    emitter.onComplete();
                });
            }, BackpressureStrategy.DROP);
        }, 1, 1)
        .map(i -> "ok:" + i)
        .blockingSubscribe();
```

this prints

```
1>>>>trigger in thread:Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
1>>>>trigger in thread:Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
1>>>>trigger in thread:Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
1>>>>trigger in thread:Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
1>>>>trigger in thread:Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
```

but if change it to `concatMap(mapper, 1)`, it prints

```
1>>>>trigger in thread:Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
1>>>>trigger in thread:Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
1>>>>trigger in thread:Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main]
1>>>>trigger in thread:Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main]
1>>>>trigger in thread:Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main]
```

Should `concatMap` also use `RxCachedThreadScheduler`? or it's intentioned.

Comment: That doesn't look right with `concatMap`. Add `hide()` between `observeOn` and `concatMap` to see if that changes things.

Comment: @akarnokd I tried and it's same that using `pool-1-thread-x`.

Comment: I see. Please try the other workarounds from [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/6447).

Comment: And for workaround, I tried to use concatMapEager with concurrency 1 first.